# API called with node.js fetch behave differently than with browser

Tags: node.js, csv, fetch

I'm using node.js to get some data on a website that uses Rest API.
First Steps :

- Connect to authent API and get a Authent Token (JWT)
- Use that token for subsequent calls

So far it works fine, i got most of the data I wanted.
Until I needed to get data from a returned CSV from the API.
It's also in two steps :

1. Get the file token (a different JWT than the authent one) : `www.site.fr/api/campain/[CampainID]`
2. Get the CSV : `www.site.fr/api/campain/[CampainID]/getfile?token=tokenFromPreviousStep`

For some reasons, if I use a API Tester (like talend API), I get the token, I call the file, evything is fine.
If I do it with fetch : I actually get a file, but the CSV header is Wrong !!

To sum up, there are two types of "campain" you can get, let's call them "TypeA" and "TypeB", each type returns CSV data with different headers.
When using node fetch, when requesting a TypeA CSV I get the correct entries, but with TypeB header... so the data is wrong because the server is trying to get some datas it doesn't have.

Where it gets really tricky is that :

- If I get the file token (step 1) with the API tester
- Then I call the CSV with fetch -> that's all good

Whereas if I get the file token with fetch and use it in the next call -> wrong CSV headers.

This the corresponding code for a static exemple:

```
// Step 1 get the Campain Token
const campainCall = await fetch("https://website.fr/api/campaigns/251611", {
   { method: "GET", headers: { Authorization: "Bearer AuthentJWT" } }
});
const campaignInfos = await campainCall.json();
const campainToken = "accessToken=" + campaignInfos.data.attributes['token-for-campaign-results'];

const fetchURL = campainURL + "251611" + endpoint + campainToken;

// Step 2 get the CSV file
const resp = await fetch(fetchURL,
    { method: "GET", headers: { Authorization: "Bearer AuthentJWT" } });
const respCSV = await resp.text();
console.log(respCSV);
```

More to know :

- I don't have any 401 response, the authent token works fine
- Once I get a correct file Token, I can get the correct file either with browser URL paste/API Tester/Fetch it always works -> Even in a fresh private session browser, if I paste the URL with the file token, I get the correct data so it seems it has **nothing to do with potential cookies**
- If the token is wrong, the file I get is always wrong (browser/fetch)
- The only way I get a "wrong" token is to get it from a node fetch call
- I can see no structural difference between a "right" and a "wrong" file token :

  - Good token : `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY2Nlc3NfaWQiOjEwMjM2ODIsImlhdCI6MTYxNjE3MjA2MiwiZXhwIjoxNjE2MTc1NjYyfQ.oUeJP3TzTml1ECpqfTKr8o3UP9dkhG6FTWF24kNiW2I`
  - wrong token : `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhY2Nlc3NfaWQiOjEwMjM2ODIsImlhdCI6MTYxNjE3MjI2NywiZXhwIjoxNjE2MTc1ODY3fQ.sWWw6fO-iXqPCZvaDqYQyxLTAw3OgMWKOZDgbedK2dk`
- I tried to copy the node fetch request from chromedev tool to see if there was a difference : nothing, the token I get from fetch is "wrong" when that very same call gave me a good token in the browser.

I know it's impossible to reproduce, but if anyone as some advice on how I could try to debug things, I've runned out of ideas...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use jwt.io to decode those JWT, both are the same, with the only difference being the issue_at and expiration timestamps.
Also, how about the `Content-Type` header? can you check if it's the same in both types of requests?
Last, could you show what's the difference in the responses?

Comment: Another question: when you talk about the "headers" being wrong, you mean the CSV headers or the http response headers?

Comment: @germanio thanks, I did check on jwt.io, the access_id is my user ID. The file ID is in the URL. I will try to add an exemple of good CSV Vs Bad CSV, but to explain : if I expect 7 lines with columnA1 columnA2... I receive in the bad CSV 7 lines but with columnB1 columnB2... I am indeed talking about CSV header. I guess since the problem comes from the file token given with fetch it has to do with how fetch does the call but as I said I did copy the same call from devtool and get a wrong token. I will double check the headers, thanks for the tracks.